# Hibernate - select entity with id from another table?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables. Property name and column name in brackets.

Table Animal has fields:
animalId (animal_id), name (name), owner (owner_id)
owner is many to one relationship to owner object and owner_id column

Table Owner has fields:
ownerId (owner_id), name

I want to select an the owner of animal who has id 5. How can that be done with hibernate?

Comment: So you haven't tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided much, but from what you're asking for.. this should work

```
Query q = sess.createQuery(" select o.owner from animal as o where o.animalId = 5")
```